# удалил XAMPP удалился сайт - как восстановить?

Tags: xampp, восстановление, htdocs

Я позавчера удалил XAMPP, т.к не смог разобраться с ошибками config'a. Однако я не знал, что тогда XAMPP удалит все веб-сайты с ним. Теперь, как я могу восстановить все мои пропавшие файлы? Есть идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

к сожалению доступ к файлам так и не удалось наладить но на будущее взял стал делать резервную копию диска С(с виндой) на Д(с файлами) раз в неделю + собираюсь подключить работу с git, чтобы все файлы проектов всегда были удаленно, чего и всем советую.